# Block Access to www.facebook.com in Android SO

Tags: android, firewall, iptables, hostname

I'm developing a framework for Android SO. I need to block a hostname, i.e. if I block a hostname, no connection is allowed to this hostname. The user will not be allowed to access this hostname by browser, terminal (shell) or any application.
I was planning to use iptables for this task, but there are some hostnames with dynamic IP address, like www.facebook.com. And I'm afraid that dynamic IP changes can affect the iptables power to block hostnames.

Can someone give me a way to block a hostname even if this hostname have a dynamic IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect it to an invalid destination via the `hosts` file, which as far as I know is located at `/system/etc/hosts`. This file should be consulted prior to DNS when trying to resolve a hostname.

```
127.0.0.1 www.blocked.domain www.blocked2.domain
```

You will need to have root-access and remount `/system/` read-write to be able to change the file.

**BEWARE:** There are ways around this. Any app that wants to "break out" can simply start doing their own DNS queries to circumvent the hosts file. But it is the only practical way to limit based on host name and not IP address.

Comment: Yes it can by doing DNS queries in your own application. But besides the iptables rules I don't see any way to prevent this and iptables rules won't work with DNS names (meaning: they would be resolved on rule creation and not on rule evaluation).

Comment: Yeah - I was going to suggest the hosts file too as a simple but limited method, my comment was more to remind the OP that all of these ideas are going to be limited.

Comment: I included your warning in the answer to point this out more prominently.

Comment: This is a good solution, but like you said, an application can resolve the hostname. Thank's for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. I'm able to block an hostname with iptables string matching. To this, i used the following commands:

    # iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m string --algo bm --string "facebook.com" -j DROP
    # iptables -A OUTPUT -m string --algo bm --string "facebook.com" -j DROP
    # iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -m string --algo bm --string "facebook.com" -j DROP

It is working fine for now.

Comment: I noticed that for some cases this solution has the same problem as occurred on @martin-c answer. The application can access the website by the IP directly.